# Schedule a Job to be done after every 5 seconds in Python(Kivy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, concurrent-processing

I Want to schedule a Job to be done after every 5 seconds which takes around 3 seconds to execute. I have used

```
kivy.uix.clock.Clock.schedule_interval(my_job, 5)
```

and

```
def my_Job():
   # Job Statements
   time.sleep(5)
   my_job()
my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_Job)
my_thread.start()
```

so far. But first one block's my design as it get executed in main Thread and second one reach

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a
> Python object

in a long run. I am stuck here, Is there anyone to help me ? Thanks

**Note:** I am using kivy to develop a desktop app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sched`. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sched.html). Note that you should not to anything that changes the kivy GUI in `my_job()` when run this way. But you can call `Clock.schedule_once()` from `my_job` to do just the GUI stuff.

Comment: Ooooooh, Such a nice Solution. Thanks John